# Using generators to write representations

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G=D_{12}=\{a,b\mid a^6=b^2=1, bab=a^{-1}\}$.

Also let
$A=\begin{pmatrix} e^{i\pi/3} & 0 \\ 0 &  e^{-i\pi/3} \end{pmatrix}$ and
$B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 &  0 \end{pmatrix}$.

I would like to prove certain systems like this are isomorphic to each other and are faithful, for a representations like $\rho_1 : a \mapsto A, b \mapsto B$ and $\rho_2 : a \mapsto A^3, b \mapsto -B$. However, I cannot see how representations like $\rho_1$ can be written as a matrix. Is it just using the direct product?

Comment: Is the question that you have different representations $\rho_i : G \to \Bbb C^2$, and you'd like to show several are equivalent? Or are you just trying to show that $\rho(G) \cong G$?

Comment: @pjs36 Different $\rho_i$. I have edited the question to make it clearer hopefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying I have limited experience with representations themselves, but much more experience with characters of representations (of finite groups).

Let $V = \Bbb C^2$ (in this case). Given representations $\mathcal{X}_1, \mathcal{X}_2 : G \to GL(V)$, the standard approach is to say that representations $\mathcal{X}_1$ and $\mathcal{X}_2$  are *similar* if there exists some invertible matrix $M \in GL(V)$ such that

$$\mathcal{X}_2 = M^{-1}\mathcal{X}_1 M.$$

Note what's happening here: each representation is a group homomorphism $G \to GL(V)$ so that composition $M^{-1}\mathcal{X}_1 M$ is thus a group homomorphism $G \to GL(V)$. Further, if $\mathcal{X}_1$ and $\mathcal{X}_2$ are similar, then $\mathcal{X}_1(G) \cong \mathcal{X}_2(G)$. So, I can't really see a need to write a representation $\mathcal{X} : G \to GL(V)$ itself as a matrix; the fact that $\mathcal{X}(g)\in GL(V)$ for each $g \in G$ is enough, if you're only concerned with whether images of representations are isomorphic.

I can't tell if you're trying to show that $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are equivalent representations (I doubt that, but I hope not), or if you're trying to work out equivalence classes of representations. In either case, I think similarity is the way to go. You could build a big block matrix with $\mathcal{X}(g)$'s down the diagonal if you really wanted a matrix for $\mathcal{X}$, but I'm not sure how useful it would be.